# How to Specify Where to Install Boom3D

Tags: windows-10, equalizer

Does anyone know how to install Boom3D to a specific drive and folder on Win10?  When I run the v1.1.6 MSI it always installs to the root of my backup USB drive and it doesn't appear there's a way to specify the install location.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the /qb (quiet mode and show a basic UI progress bar) options with INSTALLDIR="your install folder" parameter that takes that folder as the root of the install and puts Boom3D into "your install folder"\Global Delight\Boom 3D. Without the /q option, it chooses the root of the drive with the most free space, my USB backup drive in this case.  So building on @Señor CMasMas' suggestions, use the command:

msiexec /i "your msi file" INSTALLDIR="your root install folder" /qb